# Home page product slider image resize issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, small-image, image-resizing

I want a image of size **550x550** for single product slider, but my slider is getting `small_image` and resize into size **270 x270**, this leads image to be blur.
I have checked at my end and found that it is not bringing image field in product information.

Answer (score 0):

**First, log into Magento admin panel.**

Navigate to `CMS -> Static Blocks -> Slider block or CMS -> Pages -> Home page ->` Content tab that contains the coding for slider:

**In the coding look for:**

```
<div class="fluid_container">
```

**and replace with:**

```
<div class="container">
```

Using Firebug we can find out the width and height of the container:

**For Example :(Save Your Pixel Size which you want):**

Let’s replace the images with the new ones, of `1170px*510px size`. You should use Photoshop or any other images editor to adjust all images to the new size, in our case I made all images of size `1170px*510px.`

Get back to the slider coding in admin panel, and since your new image width is `1170px` and its height is `510px`, the new percentage should be `43.58%` -`(510\1170)*100= 43.58`. Change height: `‘40.357%’`, into height: `‘43.58%’`, and save the changes.

Save the changes, `clear cache` and `refresh` your website in browser to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For this I think you issue in resize function of magento

enable template path and go to that `phtml` file

where you find `resize` `method` change value of that method to `550` instead of `270`

May be you template `img` tag contain code just like below so change resize value

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(550); ?>" /> <!--change resize value to 550 instead of 270-->
```

Comment: On resize my image is taking wrong path , when i resize it to 660X600, it will take following path:  media/catalog/product/cache/4/small_image/600x600/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/h/a/hap804-blue.jpg     whereas in folder structure it doesn't have any 17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1 directory and in that place i have 040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f . When i replace it with this image occurs, suggest me a permanent solution.

Comment: @Bhagyashree magento create resize folder on the fly so this is not wrong path

Comment: @Bhagyashree go to system->cache managment and flush catalog image cache  and then refresh cache and check at frontend

Comment: no image is found at that place , I refreshed cache also.

Comment: @Bhagyashree in above my answer please write `image` instead of `small_image` and check

Comment: I tried but stil facing same issue as there is no folder in image for 600X600 resolution

Comment: @Bhagyashree please give write permission for media/catalog folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51506/discussion-between-bhagyashree-and-murtuza-zabuawala).